# Delay between DHCP Renew and ACK, should I call provider?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

Recently my home network has been working badly. All I have is a router, Tenda AC10U. The provider is giving me a dynamic IP address. (JUMP BELOW FOR TL;DR)

Long story short, lately I would often get "No Internet Connection" popping up. I would still be connected to the router through wi fi, but it will say there is no internet available. After about 5 minutes it would either fix by itself, or I would go to restart the router.

It has gotten worse, so I decided that it's time for another router. I had the old one for a little over a year. It was a cheap router so I said "that's it, time for another one". So I bought the same model.

Surprise, surprise, I still get randomly "No internet connection".

I did some investigation and I noticed that on my router's home, there is a System Log.
I noticed that when internet would drop, there would be a delay between DHCP Renew Request and the DHCP ACK received from provider's dhcp server.

**So the question is:**

Is my internet down because of the delay between DHCP Renew and DHCP Ack? Should I contact my provider?

WARNING: my internet also drops sometime, without this delay taking place.

Here you can see the delay: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccIVv.jpg
Apparently every 15 minutes my router will send the DHCP Renew. Most of the time it will get the answer instantly, but when it does not, my internet drops as well.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What type of Internet connection do you have (DSL, cable, fiber,...)?

Comment: I do not know what DSL is, but until 2 weeks ago I had a copper link. Then some workers came and changed it to fiber, but my subscription speed is limited to 100 Mb/s anyway. My internet began to drop before those guys changed my cables to fiber though.

Comment: Is it possible to connect a computer to the ISP modem (Ethernet Port) and try testing again. It seems to me that you have sufficient information to contact the ISP and ask them to fix the issue.

Comment: Hmm, I can only plug the internet cable into the router, then I could put another cable between router and a device. I cannot plug the internet cable directly into a device because the ISP is giving me internet based on MAC address somehow. But I tested with cable from router to my Smart TV and internet drops too. What it is still not clear to me is if the delay for dhcp ACK causes dead internet though.

Comment: I would contact the ISP. You should be able to put your own router at the ISP modem and then connect from there. Ask them about this and also why the irregular internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the ISP has the DHCP lease time set way too low at 30 minutes, meaning it forces the router to ask for a new IP address too often (at half time = every 15 minutes). I can imagine that if this is the case, their DHCP server is overloaded with requests from all customers, which might explain the delay time. Contact the ISP and tell them that. If you're on fiber it should obtain an IP address quickly. They probably meant to set the DHCP lease to 30 days but put in 30 minutes instead, not sure..

Just to cover your bases, make sure your router has the latest firmware, and if you happen to have another router, see if the same problem occurs with it. I doubt it will, but at least then you can tell the ISP "I tried another router and the same problem occurs".

If all else fails, get a static IP from your ISP if it's free/cheap.